# Using VIM, how do I remap directional keys from right hand to left hand?

Tags: vim, right-to-left, remap

This is the best solution I've seen so far:

```
" Map Right Directionals to Left Commands
noremap s h
noremap d k
noremap f j
noremap g l

" Map Left Commands to Right Directionals
noremap h s
noremap k d
noremap j f
noremap l g
```

However, when actually using this mapping, it requires a double-press on the 's' and 'g' keys when switching from left to right.

Is there a better way to re-map these keys to work 100% correctly without the need to double-press keys?

Comment: you may get better answers at http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also I would strongly discourage you to use these kind of mappings. The next time when working on another system, you will wonder why the keys behave so strange...

Comment: I fully agree with @Bernhard, it doesn't sound like a good idea. I'm right handed and use an ordinary mouse, with my left hand. I haven't remapped the buttons. After a few days my brain did it automatically. This has the benefit that using somebody elses computer/mouse behaves as expected.

Comment: StackOverflow is meant for programming related questions.  This question should be moved to http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea, I hope you have a good reason.

```
:map d
```

will give you a list of other commands mapped to d

```
:unmap ds
```

will unmap the ds mapping.

Once the other bindings have been removed you will only need to press the key once.